# How to create a new Java EE project in Intellij 2020.2 without Gradle or Maven?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, project

I started learning Java EE and everything was well. Today I updated my IntelliJ Ultimate version to 2020.2 and the menu to create a new project has changed.
Before, it was
[image: like this]

And now it is [image: like that]

The problem is that I can't find how to create a new project like before, with the choose of Application server and the libraries "Web Application".

Is it still possible or have I to downgrade?

Thank you very much and sorry if my question is stupid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's no longer possible. The only option is to [downgrade to 2020.1 version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html).

The previous wizard was using obsolete technologies and frameworks with the libraries hosted on JetBrains servers always lagging updates and extremely hard to maintain. Now we moved to Gradle/Maven projects where all the dependencies can be fetched from the public servers and the project can use up-to-date Java EE and library versions.

At the moment you can get the legacy project wizards back by adding `javaee.legacy.project.wizard=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restarting the IDE.

Comment: Do you have an idea why it's no longer possible ? I can't understand

Comment: @CrazyCoder could you include the *reason* in your answer?

Comment: @CrazyCoder what dependencies need to be added to maven to add the web application support?

Comment: @Michael it depends on the technologies you need. Use the wizard that will add the dependencies for you.

Comment: @CrazyCoder it sounds like the wizard went away. When you say "use the wizard that will add the dependencies for you" are you saying to add the legacy wizard back with ```javaee.legacy.project.wizard=true```

Comment: @Michael [Step 1](https://i.imgur.com/rIvs71E.png), [Step 2](https://i.imgur.com/SQ2hkht.png), then IDE creates a pom.xml and imports all the selected dependencies for you.

Comment: Moves such as this is one of the many reasons I do not use IntelliJ as my daily driver.