# Where can i find to create new servlet file with intellij?

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I'm new learner of JSP programming, so I choose intellij as my IDE.

I installed Intellij Ultimate, JDK14 from oracle,and Tomcat 9, and then searched for creating new project.

But, most of the posts which explain how to create a new servlet project says that

"when you create new project, you can find Web service checkbox under Additional Libraries and Frameworks in Java Pane."

Even JetBrains' are saying the same thing, (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-to-develop-a-web-service.html), but I couldn't find it.

[image]

Of course I checked whether my plugins are enabled.

Anyway, I found another way to create it by selecting Java Enterprise, and after clicking Next, checking "Web profile" from Libraries and Frameworks.

But now, Another problem occurs because **I cannot find "new - servlet project with right clicking on the src or src/main/java**

[image]

Why are these things happening? Even if I find some way to create servlet file, maybe there will be other problems like this, I think.

Is there any prerequiste for JSP project? or is it just because intellij has been ungraded? I wanna know the reason why my intellij is different with others.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63606566/104891.

Comment: thanks. i'm not used to intellij, so maybe i would be better using eclipse than intellij following my instructor

Comment: @cjLee Keep in mind that Eclipse has a much slower learning curve.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** If your using the Jartka EE plugin in Intellij IDEA, this should work.

I had the same problem but I did this:

1. Open Intellij IDEA Settings by *Ctrl + Alt + S*
2. Go to *Editor -> File and Code templates*
3. Add File by clicking on **+** icon
4. Name it by typing **Add new Servlet** in the *Name* field.
5. Make sure the *Extension* field is **Java**
6. Copy and Paste this text below and then click *OK* :

```java
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
import java.io.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "${NAME}Servlet", value = "/${NAME}-servlet")
public class ${NAME} extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this way I hope it works for you as it did for me. First I would recommend you to add support for Maven framework or you just could download the JAR file of the needed dependency for creating and managing servlets `Java Servlet API`.

**Adding Framework support for Maven**

On the Project tool window, you have to select the module you want to add Maven Framework support to, right-click it and select `Add Framework support`. Just like this:

[Adding Maven support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM7jm.jpg)

On the new window you just select Web Application and Maven from the list of available Frameworks. When selecting Web Application it creates a `web` package and its `web.xml` configuration file. When asked, accept creating the web.xml file to proceed. After these steps your project structure might look like this:

[Project structure after adding Maven and Web application frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Dmm.jpg)

**Adding Java Servlet API dependency to pom.xml**

Now you need to open the `pom.xml` file. This file helps you to add and manage your project dependencies as it allows you to retrieve them from the Apache Maven repository instead of downloading the JAR files and adding them manually to your project. You need to add the next dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Your pom file should look like this after the previous step:

[Adding Java Servlet API dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnosP.jpg)

As final step, we need to open the `Project Structure` settings by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S` or by navigating through `File > Project Structure`. Here we are going to find a `Project Settings` section on the left side of the window. We need to go to `Facets` and you may find a facet named `Web`. On the bottom of the window you should see an option called `Source Roots`. You have to enable it by clicking the checkbox, then click `Apply` and finally `OK`. You have to make sure that path shown in this section is indeed the path to your projects' `src > main > java` folder.

[Marking folder as source root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUJ7D.jpg)

Once you've done that, you should be able to go to any package in your project and create a servlet as follows: `New > Servlet`.

[Creating servlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhumM.jpg)

**Note:** if you got a syntax error when `pom.xml` file was created the only thing you need to do is to change the `<groupId></groupId>` tag content to a fully qualified name you want your project to be identified by.

[Given your project a qualified name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzzYm.jpg)

**Note:** I wasn't able to find a way to configure permanently the `src > main > java` folder as source root, so every time you close and reopen your project you need to go to `Project Structure (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S) > Facets > Web` and mark it as source root again. If you find a way to do this permanently I would appreciate you to share your method.

**More info on**

- [Create a Maven Project with IntelliJ IDEA](https://medium.com/@backslash112/create-maven-project-with-servlet-in-intellij-idea-2018-be0d673bd9af)
- [Getting started with Web Service](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-to-develop-a-web-service.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. right click *src\java* > *Mark directory as* > *source root*
2. go to *File > Project Structure...*
3. select *Facets*
4. click *Web(project name)*
5. check *src\main\java* under source root.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

First, you can go to src > main > java, then right click:

[image]

and then New > Create New Servlet.

Comment: Can you share how did you make the project, IntelliJ versions or some more information? mine is not showing like yours.